# Google static image api not giving image, By URL

Tags: image, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to retrieve a image from google static image api,Image URL has path coordinates but when i trying to retrieve image its not showing path.

I all ready check  my path coordinates on google map, All are correct then why image is not showing?

please help me.

here is the URL for Image :-

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=300x300&sensor=false&zoom=15&path=color:0x0000ff80%7C(47.55463,8.17993)|(47.554460000000006,8.180060000000001)|(47.554390000000005,8.180140000000002)|(47.554320000000004,8.18018)|(47.554230000000004,%208.180240000000001)|(47.55409,8.18031)|(47.5538,8.180430000000001)|(47.55304,8.1805)|(47.55265000000001,8.180530000000001)|(47.5521,8.18056)|(47.551790000000004,8.18058)|(47.55162000000001,8.180610000000001)

NOTE:-- And its a bicycle route when i m getting from google maps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `(` and `)` around coordinates. There should be `|` after `color` style parameter without `%7C`.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=300x300&sensor=false&zoom=15&path=color:0x0000ff80|47.55463,8.17993|47.554460000000006,8.180060000000001|47.554390000000005,8.180140000000002|47.554320000000004,8.18018|47.554230000000004,%208.180240000000001|47.55409,8.18031|47.5538,8.180430000000001|47.55304,8.1805|47.55265000000001,8.180530000000001|47.5521,8.18056|47.551790000000004,8.18058|47.55162000000001,8.180610000000001

See google docs [Static Map Paths](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Paths).